# GitLab project cloning into non-project files, not a new project, in PyCharm

Tags: git, pycharm, gitlab, clone

I'm having issues cloning an existing project from our workplace GitLab repository for a project our team has been working on for a few months now (I've only started this week). To do this I'm using PyCharm 2021.1 and selecting the Git tab -> Clone, entering the URL and directory, and then pressing Clone.

I've cloned other projects in this way and had no problems, but for this one project its not cloning correctly.

For this one project, once cloning is complete no new project appears in the Projects pane (see first screenshot). Instead, the Projects pane is empty and all of the python files from the project appear as non-project files, found in the Project Files pane (see second screenshot). I can still edit the non-project scripts, commit and push, but some features (like files being able to recognise functions across the project) do not work as they're not in a project.

None of my colleagues are having this issue with the same project, so not sure why I'm having this issue here (and also why all of my other projects will still clone correctly).

We believe the issue might be that my settings were incorrect originally when I cloned the file, and these settings have been corrected since (hence other projects cloning correctly) and the original settings for this one project have been saved somewhere by PyCharm or Git (Git version 2.32.0.2), hence why it still doesn't work.

Questions:

- How can we reset the history for this project so that we can reclone without the previous settings influencing it?
- Has anyone seen this before and know if its being caused by something else?

[Screenshot of PROJECTS pane after cloning has completed for this project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwZC2.png)

[Screenshot of PROJECT FILES pane after cloning has completed (PII removed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AF2Nl.png)

Thanks for the help,
Paul

Comment: same here on new pycharm 2021.3.3 (Professional Edition)